# Getting 411 Length required from nginx when making a json call

Tags: json, node.js, curl, request

Working with a new API -- MemberMouse if anyone cares/knows -- and am stuck on an "411 Length Required" response when making a request. I am successfully making the calls to the API with a php function below:

```
<?php
$inputParams = "apikey={{key}}&apisecret={{secret}}&"; 
$inputParams .= "email=ivan@email.com"; 

$apiCallUrl = "http://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php?q=/getMember";
$ch = curl_init($apiCallUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputParams); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

echo "RAW Response: ".$result."<br />"; 
$data = json_decode($result); 
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data); 
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

However I'm building my app in Node.js, and I'm trying to make a comparative call using Node's request library. Here's what I have so far.

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
url: 'http://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php',
json:true,
multipart: [

    { 
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'q': '/getMember',
            'apikey': '{{key}}',
            'apisecret':'{{secret}}',
            'email':'ivan@email.com'
        }), 
    }
],

headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
}
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
     console.log(response);
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         console.log(response);
     }
}

request.post(options, callback);
```

And it refuses to make it past nginx with a 411 Length Required Error. Anyone have any idea on what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`content-length` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)? You may need to manually set this, which would just be: `JSON.stringify({...}).length`

Comment: Yup, tried it, same response. Wasn't sure if it's supposed to be in the body or the headers section, but I've tried both individually and together to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately then, this seems like a problem for the MemberMouse folks (or someone familiar with it). Nothing we can do to debug their code. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up after hours of trying, and opted in for node-curl -- though not ideal, as it ties into OS operations, it did provide a nice way to pull the information I need. For anyone who's interested:

```
var curl = require('node-curl');


var inputParams = "apikey={{}}&apisecret={{}}&email=ivan@email.com";
var apiCallUrl = "http://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php?q=/getMember";

var options = {
    'POST':1,
    'POSTFIELDS':inputParams,
    'HEADER':0,
}


curl(apiCallUrl, options, function(error, body) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body.body)['response_data']);
});
```